# How to change huggingface transformers default cache directory

Tags: huggingface-transformers

The default cache directory is lack of disk capacity, I need change the configure of the default cache directory.

Comment: Symlinking the `huggingface` directory also works.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can specify the cache directory everytime you load a model with [.from_pretrained](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained) by the setting the parameter `cache_dir`. You can define a default location by exporting an environment variable [TRANSFORMERS_CACHE](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation?highlight=transformers_cache#cache-setup) everytime before you use (i.e. **before** importing it!) the library).

Example for python:

```
import os
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE'] = '/blabla/cache/'
```

Example for bash:

```
export TRANSFORMERS_CACHE=/blabla/cache/
```

**Update 2024**

> FutureWarning: Using `TRANSFORMERS_CACHE` is deprecated and will be
> removed in v5 of Transformers. Use `HF_HOME` instead.

Example for python:

```
import os
os.environ['HF_HOME'] = '/blabla/cache/'
```

Example for bash:

```
export HF_HOME=/blabla/cache/
```

Comment: The "before importing the module" saved me for a related problem using flair, prompting me to import flair after changing the huggingface cache env variable.

Comment: In addition, the environment variable for the datasets cache is `HF_HOME`. https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8703

Comment: first run below command on linux terminal then run first command in python code

Comment: @Ahwar you don't need both, one of them is enough.

Comment: @cronoik if you do python and jupyter notebook in vscode then you will need both. One for each.

Comment: This solution also works if you meet `OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded` for any reason.

Answer (score 54):

As @cronoik mentioned, alternative to modify the cache path in the terminal, you can modify the cache directory directly in your code. I will just provide you with the actual code if you are having any difficulty looking it up on HuggingFace:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base", cache_dir="new_cache_dir/")

model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("roberta-base", cache_dir="new_cache_dir/")
```

Answer (score 40):

You'll probably want to set the **`HF_HOME`** environment variable:

```bash
export HF_HOME=/path/to/cache/directory
```

This is because besides the model cache of HF Transformers itself, there are cache directories of other Hugging Face libraries that also eat space in the home directory. The previous answers and comments did not make this clear.

In addition, it may make sense to set a symlink to catch cases where the environment variable is not set (you may have to move away the directory `~/.cache/huggingface` before, if it exists):

```bash
ln -s /path/to/cache/directory ~/.cache/huggingface
```

In particular, the `HF_HOME` environment variable [is also respected](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/blob/2.14.4/src/datasets/config.py#L148) by Hugging Face datasets library, although the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.14.4/en/cache#cache-directory) does not explicitly state this.

The Transformers documentation [describes](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation?highlight=transformers_cache#cache-setup) how the default cache directory is determined:

> ## Cache setup
>
> Pretrained models are downloaded and locally cached at: ~/.cache/huggingface/hub. This is the default directory given by the shell environment variable TRANSFORMERS_CACHE.
>
> On Windows, the default directory is given by `C:\Users\username\.cache\huggingface\hub`. You can change the shell environment variables shown below - in order of priority - to specify a different cache directory:
>
> 1. Shell environment variable (default): HUGGINGFACE_HUB_CACHE or TRANSFORMERS_CACHE.
> 2. Shell environment variable: HF_HOME.
> 3. Shell environment variable: XDG_CACHE_HOME + /huggingface.

What this piece of documentation doesn't explicitly mention is that HF_HOME defaults to `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/huggingface` and is used for other huggingface caches, e.g. the datasets cache, which is separate from the transformers cache. The value of XDG_CACHE_HOME is machine dependent, but usually it is `~/.cache` (and HF defaults to this value if XDG_CACHE_HOME is not set) - thus the usual default `~/.cache/huggingface`

Comment: this worked for me! after setting only TRANSFORMERS_CACHE still, the cache was saved on home dir but after the three settings, it worked!

Comment: TRANSFORMERS_CACHE only controls the Hugging Face Transformers cache, i.e. for model checkpoints. Other HF libraries like [datasets](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/blob/main/src/datasets/config.py#L147), [evaluate](https://github.com/huggingface/evaluate/blob/main/src/evaluate/config.py#L115), [hub](https://github.com/huggingface/huggingface_hub/blob/main/src/huggingface_hub/constants.py#L73) and [autotrain](https://github.com/huggingface/autotrain-advanced/blob/main/src/autotrain/dataset.py#L141) have cache directories that are influenced by HF_HOME, but not by TRANSFORMERS_CACHE.

Comment: I linked to the main branch in my previous comment, so the content changes. For future reference: [datasets](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/blob/f423b6/src/datasets/config.py#L147), [evaluate](https://github.com/huggingface/evaluate/blob/d48669/src/evaluate/config.py#L115), [hub](https://github.com/huggingface/huggingface_hub/blob/25e20e/src/huggingface_hub/constants.py#L73) and [autotrain](https://github.com/huggingface/autotrain-advanced/blob/0ff192/src/autotrain/dataset.py#L142)

Answer (score 11):

Typically, you want to keep datasets and model caches around for longer but other things not. Also, these things are large and you may not want in your home folder.

So, let's say you create directory `\my_drive\hf` where you want HuggingFace to cache everything. You can create following environment variables:

```
export HF_HOME=\my_drive\hf\misc
export HF_DATASETS_CACHE=\my_drive\hf\datasets
export TRANSFORMERS_CACHE=\my_drive\hf\models
```

Now you can clean out non essential things more easily.

Note that `HF_HOME` is basically cache location of all things on Hub but above you separate out datasets and models cache. The `XDG_CACHE_HOME` is not used if `HF_HOME` is set. If it wasn't set as above then `HF_HOME` defaults to `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/huggingface`.

More info: https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/package_reference/environment_variables

Answer (score 2):

What @Cronoik said is right, but it only works for the current shell.

If you want the cache directory to be permanently changed you need to add it to `~/.bashrc` (on Linux) or similar scripts on other OS.

1. Open `~/.bashrc` in in editor. nano or Vim works fine.

   ```
    nano ~/.bashrc
   ```

   or

   ```
    vim ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Add this

   ```
    export HF_HOME="/path/to/dir"
   ```
3. Save and close the file and reopen the terminal.

Now you won't have to set it every time. It'll be permanently set to /path/to/dir

Answer (score 1):

I usually customize and modify my `cache_dir` in three ways:

**1. Setting a global environment variable.**

```bash
export TRANSFORMERS_CACHE=/path/to/my/cache/directory
```

**2. Setting the environment variable in the code**

```py
import os
from transformers import AutoModel

# Set the new cache directory
os.environ["TRANSFORMERS_CACHE"] = "/path/to/my/cache/directory"

# This directory will now be used as the cache
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

This method only affects the currently running Python script.

**3. Passing in the `cache_dir` as a parameter**

```py
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoConfig

# Set the cache directory
cache_dir = "/path/to/my/cache/directory"

# Load the model using the specified cache directory
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", cache_dir=cache_dir)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", config=config, cache_dir=cache_dir)
```

This method allows you to set the cache directory for specific models or configurations without affecting the global environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory on your host machine that is writable and mount that directory to the `/app/cache` which is a directory in the container

```
mkdir ~/my_cache

docker run -v ~/my_cache:/app/cache -e TRANSFORMERS_CACHE="/app/cache <image_name>
```