# Transformers pipeline model directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipeline, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm using the Huggingface's Transformers pipeline function to download the model and the tokenizer, my Windows PC downloaded them but I don't know where they are stored on my PC. Can you please help me? [image]

```
from transformers import pipeline

qa_pipeline = pipeline(
    "question-answering",
    model="mrm8488/bert-multi-cased-finetuned-xquadv1",
    tokenizer="mrm8488/bert-multi-cased-finetuned-xquadv1"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the default location with:

```py
import transformers #it is important to load the library before checking!
import os
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE']
```

In case you want to change the default location, please have a lock at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63314437/6664872).

Answer (score 1):

The default folder for models is at `~/.cache/huggingface`
And here's the doc from huggingface https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#cache-setup

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34535148)