# How to save HappyTransformer model in specified directory instead of ~/.cache

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets, happytransformer

I have this code that saved [HappyTransformer](https://happytransformer.com) model in `.cache/` directory by default

```
from happytransformer import HappyTextToText, TTSettings
happy_tt = HappyTextToText(model_type= "gpt")
```

I would like to automatically to save it in a specified cached directory:

```
"/home/ubuntu/storage1/various_transformer_models/"
```

What should I do?

I tried this:

```
from happytransformer import HappyTextToText, TTSettings

cache_dir = "/home/ubuntu/storage1/various_transformer_models/"
tt_settings = TTSettings(cache_dir=cache_dir)
happy_tt = HappyTextToText(model_type="gpt", tt_settings=tt_settings)
```

But failed:

```
----> 5 tt_settings = TTSettings(cache_dir=cache_dir)
      6 happy_tt = HappyTextToText(model_type="gpt", tt_settings=tt_settings)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cache_dir'
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312859/how-to-change-huggingface-transformers-default-cache-directory