# Huggingface Windows SYMLINK(?)/OSError - file that exists shows as missing

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

Trying to `train.py` a new language on [donut](https://github.com/clovaai/donut) based on a corpora I generated with their synthDOG tool, running the command `python train.py --config config/base.yaml --exp_version "base"` on up-to-date Windows 11 inside a conda virtualenv. Dev mode in Windows is activated, and I've launched Anaconda as admin, cmd also shows Administrator: at the top.

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Donut\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 1958, in _from_pretrained
    tokenizer = cls(*init_inputs, **init_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Donut\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\xlm_roberta\tokenization_xlm_roberta.py", line 168, in __init__
    self.sp_model.Load(str(vocab_file))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Donut\lib\site-packages\sentencepiece\__init__.py", line 905, in Load
    return self.LoadFromFile(model_file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Donut\lib\site-packages\sentencepiece\__init__.py", line 310, in LoadFromFile
    return _sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor_LoadFromFile(self, arg)
OSError: Not found: "C:\Users\me\.cache\models--naver-clova-ix--donut-base\snapshots\a959cf33c20e09215873e338299c900f57047c61\sentencepiece.bpe.model": No such file or directory Error #2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Kontron\donut-master\train.py", line 149, in <module>
    train(config)
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Kontron\donut-master\train.py", line 57, in train
    model_module = DonutModelPLModule(config)
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Kontron\donut-master\lightning_module.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.model = DonutModel.from_pretrained(
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Kontron\donut-master\donut\model.py", line 594, in from_pretrained
    model = super(DonutModel, cls).from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, revision="official", *model_args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Donut\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py", line 2498, in from_pretrained
    model = cls(config, *model_args, **model_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Kontron\donut-master\donut\model.py", line 390, in __init__
    self.decoder = BARTDecoder(
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Kontron\donut-master\donut\model.py", line 159, in __init__
    self.tokenizer = XLMRobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Donut\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 1804, in from_pretrained
    return cls._from_pretrained(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Donut\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 1960, in _from_pretrained
    raise OSError(
OSError: Unable to load vocabulary from file. Please check that the provided vocabulary is accessible and not corrupted.
```

When running by default, the cache link is incorrect, as it generates something like "C:\User\me/.cache\etc.". I manually changed the cache, but still after downloading about a GB of model files, the folder only contains SYMLINK files that are 0 KB. Even when I manually downloads all the files and add them in, the path won't be recognized (please do note the path is now NOT mixing / and \ together like it did by default). Copy-pasting the apparently erroneous file path from the cmd stack trace to a python `with open()` command, it seems to open it just fine. I have no idea what's wrong, but I'd really like some help, I'm going crazy. It's saying files aren't there, but they are.

Comment: No clue about windows, but can you try to load the model in a python interpreter, maybe by explicitly specifying the [cache_dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312859/how-to-change-huggingface-transformers-default-cache-directory/63314437#63314437)?