# No model was supplied, defaulted to

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm getting started using the transformers library from HuggingFace.co.  When I run the below file, it works, but I get an error indicating I'm not following best practices.

```
from transformers import pipeline 
print(pipeline('sentiment-analysis')('I love you'))
```

When I run that file with `python main.py` I get this error:

> 2.014 No model was supplied, defaulted to distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english and revision af0f99b
> (https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english).
>
> 2.014 Using a pipeline without specifying a model name and revision in production is not recommended.

But when I google that error message, this question doesn't show up with the best practice for specifying a model and revision.  Additionally, assuming it's not too involved, I'd also like to see how the model can be cached, say, when building a Dockerfile in an elegant way.  Is there perhaps a way of having models download by stuffing them into the requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message you see there is not an error message, it is just a warning. It tells you, that the pipeline is using [distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english](https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english) because you haven't specified a model_id. In other words, it might not yield the best results for your use case.

There are plenty of models available on the [hub](https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=text-classification&sort=downloads&search=sentiment) you should play around with a few to find the one that yields the best results. You can use them by specifying the [model](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TextClassificationPipeline.model) parameter of the `__init__` method:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

model_id = "cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest"

sentiment_pipe = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=model_id)
print(sentiment_pipe('I love you'))
```

Regarding docker:

Just run a .py-script that loads the pipeline once as a step of your dockerfile. It will automatically [cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312859/how-to-change-huggingface-transformers-default-cache-directory/63314437#63314437) the files. You can also save it directly to a specific location with [save_pretrained](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.Pipeline.save_pretrained):

```py
# run this either before building the container an cp the `my_pipe` directory to the container later
sentiment_pipe.save_pretrained("my_pipe")

# load it inside the container
sentiment_pipe = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model="my_pipe")
print(sentiment_pipe('I love you'))
```