# Huggingface out of space disk downloading the model

Tags: azure, huggingface-transformers, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using the following code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import transformers
import torch
model = "meta-llama/Llama-2-70b-chat-hf"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model,use_auth_token=True,cache_dir='/mnt/test')
```

but during the download process for the model in question, the Azure machine Learning compute goes out of space. for this reason I change the cache_dir but it still goes out of memory saving the model download in the default .cache/huggingface/hub. The /mnt/test is mount on a second disk of Azure ML compute where I have 1200GB.
any advice to avoid the problem?

Comment: Is it the first model you are downloading? HF by default saves every model you run in a .cache folder. So maybe you could clear it to free some memory

Comment: yes it is the first model. the model itself is 150gb but I have 120gb. how can I change the destination folder to download?

Comment: Have you tried setting the TRANSFORMERS_CACHE environment variable to change the cache directory for the transformers? [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312859/how-to-change-huggingface-transformers-default-cache-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information, it seems that changing the `cache_dir` parameter is not working as expected.
One possible solution to this is by setting the `TRANSFORMERS_CACHE` environment variable to the desired cache directory before importing the `transformers` library.

```py
import os
os.environ["TRANSFORMERS_CACHE"] = "new_cache_path"
```

With this, the model is downloading to the custom cache path.
[image]

Please check Huggingface cache setup [description](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation?highlight=transformers_cache#cache-setup) for details.